# Why does class='active' get stripped and is there a way around it?

Tags: plone, diazo

What i'm trying to do is replace the header structure on the content side to make some drastic structure changes, in order to move the whole header to the theme side in one go.

My problem is this, I can not replace the 'selected' class on list items with 'active'. The globalnav in this case is three levels deep with different structure for the different levels, so it's a bit big to post in one go. The basic idea is this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="globalnav" css:select="#portal-globalnav"/>
    <replace css:content="#portal-header">
        <ul id="borked-nav">
          <xsl:for-each select="$globalnav/li">
            <li>
              <xsl:if test="./@class = 'selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </replace>
```

What does work for instance is:

```
<xsl:variable name="globalnav" css:select="#portal-globalnav"/>
<replace css:content="#portal-header">
    <ul id="borked-nav">
      <xsl:for-each select="$globalnav/li">
        <li>
          <xsl:if test="./@class = 'selected'">
             <xsl:attribute name="class">super-active</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</replace>
```

What does not work (ends up class="really"):

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">active really active</xsl:attribute>
```

or define $active in the theme panel and try using  or actually changing the template with jbot to have the class active (I tried to just add, so 'selected active really' as a class in the template in jbot would produce a class 'selected really').

I can not reproduce it in a simple setup, so I will post the complete code below. Does anyone have a clue why it gets stripped, I'm not using 'active' anywhere in my rules. The snippet below is in an xinclude with the variables defined in the rules.xml.

```
<replace css:content="#portal-header">
 <div id="header">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="menu-button">
      <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <a class="logo" href="{$logo/@href}" accesskey="{$logo/@accesskey}" title="{$logo/@title}" ></a>
    <span class="search-button">
      <span class="label">Zoeken...</span><span class="icon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul class="main-level">
        <xsl:for-each select="$globalnav/li">
          <li class="{@class}">
            <xsl:comment>
              <xsl:if test="@class = 'selected'">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">super-active</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./a"/>
            <xsl:if test="./ul">
              <div class="mega-menu level-1">
                <div class="menu-left-wrapper">
                  <h2>Onderwerpen</h2>
                  <ul class="sub-level-1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./ul/li">
                      <li class="{@class}">
                        <xsl:comment>
                          <xsl:if test="@class = 'selected'">
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">super-active</xsl:attribute>
                          </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:comment>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./a"/>
                        <xsl:if test="./ul">
                          <div class="mega-menu">
                            <h2>Artikelen binnen onderwerp</h2>
                            <ul class="sub-level-2">
                              <xsl:for-each select="./ul/li">
                                <li>
                                  <xsl:if test="@class = 'selected'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:if>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="./a"/>
                                </li>
                              </xsl:for-each>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </xsl:if>
                      </li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="$articles">
          <li class="light">
            <a class="" href="#">Snel naar<span class="arrow"></span></a>
            <div class="mega-menu level-1">
              <div class="menu-left-wrapper">
                <h2><xsl:apply-templates select="$articles-heading"/></h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$articles"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </xsl:if>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <xsl:if test="$helpdesks or $products">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="content">
          <xsl:if test="$helpdesks">
            <h2><xsl:apply-templates select="$helpdesks-heading"/></h2>
            <div class="buttons">
              <xsl:for-each select="$helpdesks/li/a">
                <a href="{./@href}" class="button phone"><xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/></a>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$products">
            <h2><xsl:apply-templates select="$products-heading"/></h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$products"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>

    <div class="top-menu">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$siteactions"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search">
    <span class="search-button">
      <span class="label">Zoeken...</span><span class="icon"></span>
    </span>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
      <form id="search-form" action="{$searchform/@action}">
        <div class="form-item">
          <div class="content">
            <input type="text" name="{$searchfield/@name}" id="keyword"/>
            <span class="border"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Zoek" class="submit"/>
        <span class="submit-button"><span class="label">Zoeken</span><span class="icon"></span></span>
        <span class="close-button"><span class="icon"></span></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</replace>
```

I have now changed it to only handle the globalnav and then move over the li's into the theme like so:

```
<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav a">
  <a><xsl:copy-of select="./@*|./*|./text()"/><span class="arrow"></span></a>
</replace>

<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav li.selected">
  <li class="active"><xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/></li>
</replace>

<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav .submenu">
  <div class="mega-menu level-1">
    <div class="menu-left-wrapper">
      <h2>Onderwerpen</h2>
      <ul class="sub-level-1"><xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</replace>

<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav .submenu .submenu ">
  <div class="mega-menu">
    <h2>Artikelen binnen onderwerp</h2>
    <ul class="sub-level-2"><xsl:apply-templates select="./*"/></ul>
  </div>
</replace>
```

And I have conferred with the design/front-end party to not use the 'active' class in the static html, it still gets stripped.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit more passive. It worked for me. Hopefully I understood your question right and it will help you.
To look if an attribute contains a value is more safe most of the time.

```
<replace css:content="#portal-globalnav">
    <ul id="borked-nav">
        <xsl:for-each css:select="#portal-globalnav > li">
            <xsl:variable name="class" select="./@class" />
            <li>
                <xsl:if test="contains(@class, 'selected')">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
 </replace>
```

I see you're rewriting a lot of markup inside the replace tag. Have you thought about actually changing the template instead of doing all of this on the fly.

This works great but it's better to keep your ruleset tight as it isn't closely as fast as the template engine.

Comment: This way would be inefficient since inside the replace you can use '.' in selects to refer to #portal-globalnav. But in my case it still strips 'active', I had tried to change the template (with jbot), but it still gets stripped. Even if I use the class="active" in the footer, so not anywhere in the globalnav or header area.

Comment: I have also commented out all other rules not related to the header to rule out anything happening there, still no 'active'.

Comment: I know, but i wanted to write it this way as it is a bit more readable.
This sounds very mysterious. So no matter what you do, the word active gets stripped on the whole site?

Comment: I should actually check that, so far I have been paying attention to the class attributes.

Comment: 'active' gets tripped as a class some of the time, in the global nav all of the time, I haven't found the common denominator yet.